# Selecting just the first row from a search cursor

Tags: arcpy

Currently I am trying to select the top row of a feature class which is sorted using a Count field. I then would like to run the script a second time but the result will then be the second row of the table. I currently have the script below.

```
#import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "D:\\Trimble.gdb"

#allow overwrites
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#print list of feature classes
featList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print featList

#cheack if Messages and Township spatial join has been made
for feat in featList:
    if arcpy.Exists("TWP_Messages"):
        print "Township and Messages Without Roads joined already"
        print ""
        break
    else:
        #create spatial join between Messages and Townships
        target_features = "D:\\Trimble.gdb\\TWP"
        join_features = "D:\\Trimble.gdb\\Messages"
        out_feature = "D:\\Trimble.gdb\\TWP_Messages"
        arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features, join_features, out_feature)

        #sort Join_Count field by Descending
        arcpy.Sort_management("TWP_Messages", "TWP_Messages_Sort",     [["Count_", "DESCENDING"]])
        print arcpy.GetMessage(2)
        messageSort = "D:\\Trimble.gdb\\TWP_Messages_Sort"

        #add field to messages sort feature to describe if item has been deleted already
        arcpy.AddField_management(messageSort, "Downloaded", "TEXT")
        #update all Downloaded fields to No
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(messageSort, "Downloaded") as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                row[0] = "No"
                cursor.updateRow(row)
        del row
        del cursor

messageSorted = "D:\\Trimble.gdb\\TWP_Messages_Sort"
i = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(messageSorted, ["DESCRIPTOR", "Count_"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1] != i:
            print("Descriptor: {}    Count: {}".format(row[0], row[1]))
            i = row[1]
            name = row[0]
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(messageSorted, ["Count_", "Downloaded"]) as curs:
                for line in curs:
                    if line[0] == i:
                        line[1] = "Yes"
                        curs.updateRow(line)
            break

print name
```

Currently it is rewriting the fields it updates (Downloaded) every time and does not remember where it left off. Obviously the break is causing a problem here too.

I thought about making a table that updates each item that has previously been selected so then the search could check there and continue on to the next needed row. Unsure how to implement that too.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a few lines of the attribute table that show what you have and what you want to happen?  You have the table sorted by count, and then you want Yes to be written under Downloaded . . . . when? Or, rather, what would be the situation where you'd want Downloaded to remain No?

Comment: There's an awful lot of "snippet" code for the task of getting the first row.  Since DA Cursors return an array you could just return element zero. Or, faster, use the cursor.next() operator to return *only* the first row. Or add a `break` in the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: I have actually rewritten everything of this in a much nicer script which is working a million times better. I will delete the question but just wanted to say thank you for taking the time to look this over.

Comment: What is your ultimate objective?

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this I have rethought the process and have come up with this code which is working exactly how I wanted. Just had to get past the old brain muddling.

```
#import arcpy module
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\\Trimble.gdb"

#create variable of the sorted message and township feature class
messageSorted = "D:\\Trimble.gdb\\TWP_Messages_Sort"

#select the first row of the feature that has not been downloaded previously
i = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(messageSorted, ["TRM", "Downloaded"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if i == 1:
            break
        else:
            if row[1] == "Yes":
                continue
            else:
                TWP = row[0]
                i += 1

print TWP
del row
del cursor

#update the new selected line to downloaded so it is not selected again
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(messageSorted, ["TRM", "Downloaded"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == TWP:
            row[1] = "Yes"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
del row
del cursor
```

Comment: That's still gobs more complicated than putting a non-conditional break after the inner `if` and removing the outer `if`.  You also don't need to delete the cursor (`with` handles that)